# What topics (basics or foundations or fundamentals or what) to learn/study before studying K&R's "The C Programming Language"?

Tags: c

I don't know programming, I don't know any programming language (only some HTML if it can be called programming language). I only studied Petzold's "CODE" so far just to learn basics.

I decided to learn basics and (at least) some C first (even if some suggest JS, Python or other languages first).

To learn C, people often suggest studying K&R's book "The C Programming Language" after learning basics of programming. (Even in the book they say that the book is not for beginners)

People often sat "it's important to learn basics/fundamental/foundations first" and stress about basics and foundations without telling what they are.

**Basics basics basics. . . foundations foundations foundations. . . what topics, concepts, etc. do the basics (or foundations or fundamemtals or what they call it) involve?**

NOTE: I don't ask for book or course recommendation, but I ask for what topics/concepts to learn to get a foundation.

Comment: I think you can start with that book. (I did.) There are a few things in there that might be a bit of a challenge at first if you are a complete beginner (pointer to pointers...), but nothing too heavy. Knowing something about unixy things might help though, like file descriptors and some shell programming.

Comment: Well, the *right* way to do it is to start with FORTRAN, then BASIC, then assembly language, then COBOL.  APL next, and only then are you allowed to touch a mixed-case language (Pascal).

Comment: You can learn things in parallel. I'd suggest starting K&R. I started it a year ago and I'm still not done... Read for understanding (if you don't understand a word/phrase or concept, you can look it up).

Comment: @Hot Licks: You made my day! (I expect the OP not to take your comment seriously :))

Comment: @KemyLand - Why would anyone not take it seriously?  It's how I learned.

Comment: @Hot Licks: Well, I really didn't expected that...

Answer (score 4):

Hell, raw theory is boring and that's not what programming is!

I'm not expecting *anyone* who's learning to program to study *raw and crude* theory first. The best way you can learn is by trail-and-return-non-zero, trail-and-SIGSEGV, and some day, trail-and-return-zero.

Anyway, if you already have some knowledge of algebra, electronics, or even some computer science, that'll definitely help you, **But**, if you don't know something like that, *don't* learn it just for the sake of preparation.

It's pretty debatable whether HTML is a programming language, but anyway, you'll enter in another world/dimension/universe/existence by learning C.

The C language is, IMHO, a very neat language. May it not be as flexible (and thus, dirty) as C++, but it's neat and elegant. It's simple. Once you know C, and can read/write it fluently, you could even (more or less) understand parts of the [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) for example.

You mentioned both Javascript and Python. I wouldn't go with Javascript unless you're of those impure people who want to learn programming just for a job, and not for entertainment/fun, *which is the real magic and beatifulness behind it!* Python would be something I would recommend, but you already know C is somewhat harder, and you want to go that way, so go that way!

I'm not sure how much to recommend to you K&R. It was never updated after ANSI C (a standard from *1988-90*!). That makes it pretty outdated (the latest C standard is from 2011, and the previous one was from 1999 (without C99 you'll experiment hell sooner or later)). Many (and I mean *too much*) people has though of *The C Programming Language* as "being the authoritative reference for C", because it was (in part) written by [Dennis MacAlistair Ritchie (1941-2011)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Ritchie), or in other words, the Messiah and Creator of C, who came to save us from [Fortran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran).

Although some other answer may better answer you which books may be recommended (I can't, because I wasn't taught by books, but by Google), I hope this answer will give some light on what you should do. Happy programming :)!

Comment: "trail-and-return-non-zero, trail-and-SIGSEGV, and some day, trail-and-return-zero." Could I ask what do you mean?

Comment: @Coder88: That's just sort of a joke with technical terminology. It basically means "trail-and-fail, trail-and-fail, trail-and-succeed".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think very much is required to start reading K&R for comprehension. Although it is not written for novices, it is not novice-unfriendly. It does cover the very basic concepts of variables, functions, if-else statements, memory addresses, etc. with due diligence. It *can* stand alone as a programming tutorial. I think the main obstacles to newcomers would be programming terminology and a basic grasp of how to express a task as a series of logical steps in an algorithm (i.e., in code).

In my own opinion, C is an excellent choice for first programming language, and K&R is an excellent choice for learning C. I read K&R at a time when I had already studied C in college, but I remember wishing that it had been the first C programming book I had ever read. It presents the C language and its standard library very succinctly and in a way that is consistent with its design philosophy (makes sense, since it's written by the creators of C). This is not something you will get from reading books with titles such as "C for Engineers", which guide you through just enough of the language to succeed in a specific line of work. K&R presents C as a language -- it shows you the whole toolbox.

Is K&R the *ideal* book specifically for beginners? Probably not. Do I recommend it? Yes. It's written as an introduction to C, not to programming in general. But the gap isn't so wide that it is insurmountable. It is not necessary to be familiar with any of the past languages mentioned in the introduction (to this day I've never written a line of Fortran or Pascal in my life), nor is it necessary to know any particulars about machine language.

C itself is a relatively minimal programming language which maps closely to the primitives of procedural programming (variables, control statements like while and if/else, functions) and computer architecture (pointers, arrays, strong typing, memory allocation). Learning C will force you to become familiar with these concepts, which make up the technology underlying other languages like Java, Python, JavaScript, and so on. Consequently you will end up with a deeper understanding of software in general, and it will make you well-prepared to pick up those languages down the line if you choose.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely recommend you the following book: [Learn C The Hard Way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/).

Zed Shaw, the author of this book, is a person who totally understands the difference between a beginner programmer (someone who understands the fundamentals) and a total beginner (someone like you). You can read more about his ideas about this [here](http://zedshaw.com/2015/06/16/early-vs-beginning-coders/).

The book is almost entirely available online and a physical copy will be published soon.

Maybe after reading this book you should read the K&R's one.

Note: The name of the book does not mean that the book is hard by the way.